# Where can I find a specific electron binding for node-sqlite3

Tags: electron

**Background**

When I try and build `node-sqlite3` within `Electron` it fails when trying to download the binding for Electron on Windows.

**Example**

```
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.0.8/electron-v4.2-win32-x64.tar.gz
```

**Question**

Where can I download this file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you found the answer after opening this issue. Wanted to go ahead and answer this question for others struggling.

Issue Opened:
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1163

Actual binding:
https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.0.0/electron-v4.0-win32-x64.tar.gz